# Using the Definition of Uniform Convergence to Prove : $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n!}$ in any Finite Interval

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

$$\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n!} = 1 + \frac{x}{1!} + \frac{x^2}{2!} + ...$$

is uniform convergent for any finite interval.

I need to show that $\forall \ \epsilon > 0 \ \exists  \ N $ such that when $n > N $ the remainder $|R_n(x)| < \epsilon$ where $N$ is not dependent on $x$.

What I want to do is work with the remainder $R_n(x) = \frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!} + \frac{x^{n+2}}{(n+2)!} + ...$ and somehow create use inequality that makes it not dependent on $x$ and then set $\epsilon$ to be less then that. However, I am unable to find this relation. Could someone provide a proof strategy that works?

Comment: This is not true.  For $x = n$ you always have $R_n(x) \gg 1$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{k=n+1}^{+\infty}\frac{x^k}{k!}=\int_0^x\frac{(x-t)^n}{n!}e^t{\rm d}t$$
Thus
$$ \left|\sum_{k=n+1}^{+\infty}\frac{x^k}{k!}\right|\leqslant\frac{e^x|x|^{n+1}}{(n+1)!} $$
If $a<b$, then for all $x\in [a,b]$, we have
$$ \left|\sum_{k=n+1}^{+\infty}\frac{x^k}{k!}\right|\leqslant\frac{e^b\max(|a|,|b|)^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}\underset{n\rightarrow +\infty}{\longrightarrow}0 $$
The convergence is uniform on all the segments of $\mathbb{R}$.